# Magento 2 - How to Hide/Show custom attribute based on customer group?

Tags: magento2.3.3

I want to **hide/show** custom attribute based on customer group value.
**Can anyone suggest me how can I do this?**

Any help would be appreciated.

**Thanks in advance..!**

[image]

1. I want to hide custom field 'Ware House',if customer group is
   'General,Wholesale or Retailer.
2. If customer group is Test Group-1 or Test Group-2,then load sources 
   based on selected customer group

Comment: from you want to show?please  provide more info

Comment: @AmitBera Please look my updated question..

Comment: any solution for this